# How to initialize USB in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, usb-flash-drive, bootable

So I'm trying to create a bootable USB to help out in tech support for some friends. I decide to got with [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) as some of my family members don't have such powerful machines.

I buy a flash drive only to be met by this error once I insert it.
[image: The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.]

All dandy I can probably fix this. I open up Disk Utility; navigate to the drive and try to run first aid hoping to get it up and running in no time. *And*, **boom** error:

```
Fixing damaged partition map.

The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.DiskManagement error -69874.)

Operation failed…
```

Ok, a usable error I can google. **Boy was I wrong**, I found a whole load of nothing. So I do some digging in the [terminal docs](https://www.apple.com/server/docs/Command_Line.pdf) and come up with this command: `diskutil eraseVolume ExFAT MyName disk3`.
which returns another error:

```
Started erase on disk3
Unmounting disk
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

which lead me here. Is my drive halve DOA or is there some simple fix?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using macOS, in this case, I would suggest using [etcher.io](https://etcher.io/) since the process is pretty easy and straightforward.

In case you would like to do it from the terminal and already have the image, you could do something like this:

Firs find your USB try this command:

```
$ diskutil list
```

Lest assume is `/dev/disk3`, then try to unmount it

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3
```

Now use the `dd` command, keep in mint it will destroy any existing data on the target disk:

```
$ sudo dd bs=1m if=latest-USB.img of=/dev/rdisk3
```

Notice the `r - raw` in of `/dev/rdisk3`